# C# MySql passing parameters with a specific row in database from one form to another

Tags: c#, mysql, forms, parameters

Hello guys I would like to ask for help
I've created a simple enrollment system that is connected to mysql database

I have a form that you will create a simple personal info with username and password so after you create it will save in my database

All i want is when I will now login with that set of username and password
there's a new form that will pop out and there are 4 labels there .
The 4 labels should change into the personal details of the set of username and password which I've created

So how can I pass it into another form, How can I change the level into the specific details of the username

here's my code for FORM1(LOGIN form):

```
private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();

        if (comboBox1.Text == "ADMIN")
        {
            if (textBox1.Text.Equals("ADMIN") && textBox2.Text.Equals("PASSWORD"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("LOGIN SUCCESS");
                this.Hide();
                frm2.Show();
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("INCORRECT USERNAME OR PASSWORD!");
            }
        }
        else if (comboBox1.Text=="USER"){
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
            //MySqlCommand cmd;
            //connection.Open();



            string selectString =
                                    "SELECT username, password " +
                "FROM enrollment_system " +
                "WHERE username = '" + textBox1.Text + "' AND password = '" + textBox2.Text + "'";

                MySqlCommand mySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(selectString, connection);
                connection.Open();
                String strResult = String.Empty;
                strResult = (String)mySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                connection.Close();

                try
                {
                    if (strResult.Length == 1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("FAIL TO LOGIN");
                        //could redirect to register page
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("GOOD TO LOGIN"+samples);
                        this.Hide();
                        Form6 frm6 = new Form6(this);
                        frm6.Show();
                        frm6.studentid = textBox1.Text;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Fail to login");
                }

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("SELECT ACCOUNT TYPE");
        }
    }


Form 6( the form that will pop out and represents as the student info)
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication17
{
    public partial class Form6 : Form
    {
        Form1 AccountForm { get; set; }
        public string studentid;
        public string firstname;
        public string lastname;
        public string middle;
        public string course;
        public string yearlevel;
        public string type;
        public Form6(Form1 _form1)//
        {
            AccountForm = _form1;
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST)
                m.Result = (IntPtr)(HT_CAPTION);
        }

        private const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;
        private const int HT_CLIENT = 0x1;
        private const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;
        private void Form6_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            labelStudent.Text = studentid;
            labelCourse.Text = course;
            /*
            labelYear.Text = yearlevel;
            labelType.Text = type;*/
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: First of all, use properties on your Form6 rather than fields. Secondly, you need to set these properties before you .Show() the form.

Comment: Is there a reason you haven't made a student class, and are building it into the form?

Comment: I understand that this is just a personal test project of sorts, but are you storing the password in plain text? You should search around for [password hashing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa545602(v=cs.70).aspx). Hash the password, store that, and check against the hash instead of plain text.

Comment: Yeah Maybe I could do that later but My problem right now is to get the value of the other textfields in the same row of USERNAME

SO i can get the value of that and change the label of my form
that's the important for now

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE username = '" + textbox1.Text + "';"; and use a data reader

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing:

```
Form6 frm6 = new Form6(this);
frm6.Show();
frm6.studentid = textBox1.Text;
```

Try doing:

```
Form6 frm6 = new Form6(this);
frm6.studentid = textBox1.Text;
frm6.Show();
```

Notice that in the latter snippet, you are showing the form **after** you set the correspondent properties.

In the former approach, modifying controls on an already shown form will require you to invalidate (repaint) it in order to actually see the changes.

Comment: Yeah but i need specific details. I have to select those on database. so how can i do that?